# Regex all uppercase with special characters

Tags: mysql, regex

I have a regex '^[A0-Z9]+$' that works until it reaches strings with 'special' characters like a period or dash.

List:

```
UPPER
lower
UPPER lower
lower UPPER
TEST
test
UPPER2.2-1
UPPER2
```

Gives:

```
UPPER
TEST
UPPER2
```

How do I get the regex to ignore non-alphanumeric characters also so it includes UPPER2.2-1 also?

I have a link here to show it 'real-time': http://www.rubular.com/r/ev23M7G1O3

This is for MySQL REGEX

EDIT: I didn't specify I wanted all non-alphanumeric characters (including spaces), but with the help of others here it led me to this: '^[A-Z-0-9[:punct:][:space:]]+$' is there anything wrong with this?

Comment: Are you aware that `[A0-Z9]` matches any digit, any upper-case letter plus any of the following: `:;<=>=?@` (because it creates a range from 0 to Z in ASCII order)?

Comment: Updated the question above, how does '^[A-Z-0-9[:punct:][:space:]]+$' look?

Comment: So you want everything except for lower-case letters?

Comment: @DavidRebbe, do you just want all non whitespace, or just all non lowercase and whitespace?

Comment: I'm basically trying to find all uppercase that can be more than one word with characters like " ' , . - + =. I guess everything but lower-case should work.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
'^[A-Z0-9.-]+$'
```

You just need to add the special characters to the group, optionally escaping them.

Additionally if you choose not to escape the `-`, be aware that it should be placed at the start or the end of the grouping expression to avoid the chance that it may be interpreted as delimiting a range.

---

To your updated question, if you want all non-whitespace, try using a group such as:

```
^[^ ]+$
```

which will match everything except for a space.

If instead what you wanted is all non-whitespace and non-lowercase, you likely will want to use:

```
^[^ a-z]+$
```

The 'trick' used here is adding a caret symbol after the opening `[` in the group expression. This indicates that we want the *negation* of the match.

Following the pattern, we can also apply this 'trick' to get everything *but* lowercase letters like this:

```
^[^a-z]+$
```

I'm not really sure which of the 3 above you want, but if nothing else, this ought to serve as a good example of what you can do with character classes.

Comment: I think he even wants whitespace.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you are looking for (one?) uppercase-word match, where word is pretty much anything.

```
^[^a-z\s]+$
```

...or if you want to allow more words with spaces, then probably just

```
^[^a-z]+$
```

Comment: He wants whitespace, too. Otherwise, this is it, I think.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to put in the `.` and `-`. In theory, you don't need to escape because they are inside the brackets, but I like to to remind myself to escape when I have to.

```
'^[A-Z0-9\.\-]+$'
```

Comment: Alright. In this case there is no need for escaping ;) (dots never have to be escaped inside character classes, and hyphens don't if they are the last character)

Comment: My theory is to escape even if you don't have to, to remember to escape when you need to. But maybe that's just me...

Comment: Agreed with @m.buettner you don't need to escape special characters in character classes.

Comment: And the initial character class (`A0-Z9`) is still messed up ;)

Comment: I thought that odd, but I thought it might be some wierd regex syntax that I'd never seen. Fixed again.

Comment: @fardjad I get Pearsonartphoto's point though, and it's perfectly valid. It's just a matter of taste. I like to remove as much clutter as possible from regular expressions, and that means reducing escapes to a minimum. That, of course, is more error prone, if anyone touches the regex who doesn't know about the significance of certain character positions.

Answer (score 0):

Try regular expression as below:

```
   '^[A0-Z0\\.\\-]+$'
```